# How to stop caching in web console when viewing code file

Tags: php, html, web-console

Trying to debug a PHP file which has a syntax error using Firefox web console.  I have set the Disable Cache option and when I change the file it does take effect immediately.  However, the console displays the syntax error and when I click on the link in the message it opens a tab with the code page and highlights a line, but the page displayed is before the last change.  If I open a new tab and repeat the process I get the updated code.

I find this very confusing, is there any way to make it use the current code?

Comment: share your code here

Comment: Yes, just changed the code, reload the page, I see the change on screen, press Ctrl F5, view the syntax error link and it is the old code.

Answer (score 0):

append this..

```
<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Comment: Just tried that and it made no difference, still see the previous code.